# Django prefetch_related with generic relation for a list not an object

Tags: django, django-queryset

```
class Album:

    songs = models.ManyToManyField(Song)

class Song:

    title = models.CharField()
    ratings = GenericRelation(Rating)
    modified_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, db_index=True)


class Rating:

    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
    time_stamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, db_index=True)
```

For a user, I'd like to list songs in an album.

I'd like to show if each song has been modified after the user has rated the song.

In a code,

```
if Rating.objects.filter(user=user,
    content_type=ContentType.objects.get_for_model(song), object_id=song.id, 
    time_stamp__lt=song.modified_at).exists():
    # song has been modified after user has rated it
```

I have the following at the moment, and the query fails with an error 
`Cannot resolve keyword 'content_type' into field. Choices are: title, ratings, modified_at`

The `content_type` that error is referring to is `content_type` implied in `ratings = GenericRelation(Rating)` I think.

```
qs = album.songs.all()

album.songs.prefetch_related(
    Prefetch(
        'ratings',
        queryset=qs.filter(
            ratings__user=user,
            ratings__rating_type=RATING_TYPE_VIEW
        ).annotate(time_stamp=Max('ratings__time_stamp')),
        to_attr='ratings_prefetched'
    )
)
```

I'm on django 1.8.4

Comment: Why are you using `content_type=song_content_type`? Song doesn't have such attribute.

Comment: it's just a variable I named.. I can change the code

Comment: If you have the song object, then you can  call like 'if song.ratings.all().filter(user=user,time_stamp__lt=song.modified_at).exists():'

Comment: Yes, the question is to do that for all the songs in a given album efficiently.